# Filter or sort Google search results by "number of posts"

Tags: google-search

I love the "X Posts" flourish that adorns certain Google search results (usually indicating that the link leads to some sort of forum).

[image: post results]

Is there a way to limit results *to only those with posts*, or *sort results* by number of posts?

Answer (score 1):

Typically results mentioning "posts" indicate that they are from some sort of a forum. Try [Google Groups Search](http://groups.google.com/) if you are looking for results that have a certain number of posts. Google Groups Search now gets results from [not just threads within Google Groups but also other forums](http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/018627.html).